# any one knows where I could find (or I could make) a function that calculate moon phase ? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm looking for a small fucntion in ActionScript 3 that could calculate Moon Phases. 
I've tried to search on google. The only result is a website that gives this code but I think it's a wrong code.

```
//return frame number for moon phase display
function getMoonPhase(yr:Number, m:Number, d:Number):int{
//based on http://www.voidware.com/moon_phase.htm
//calculates the moon phase (frames 1-30 )

if (m < 3) { yr -= 1; m += 12; } //
m += 1; 
var c:Number = 365.25*yr; 
var e:Number = 30.6*m; //jd is total days elapsed 
//divide by the moon cycle (29.53 days) 
var jd:Number = (c+e+d-694039.09)/29.53; //subtract integer to leave fractional part
jd = jd - int(jd); //range fraction from 0-30 and round by adding 0.5 
var frame:int = Math.round(jd*30 + 0.5);
return frame; 
} 
//test: september 23, 2002, not a full moon? //
```

Weirdly, sometimes the code is extremely accurate, but sometimes it's wrong..

Example : On the 16 september 2016 it's a full moon. 
But if I enter this date in the code the result is "15" (16 is full moon)....

Any idea why ? or another way to calculate moon phases ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

In that algorithm, `c` is int, not `Number`, therefore an implicit round-down occurs here. Same with `e`. This can total to a one day error in calculation which in turn produces wrong phase.

Edit: Also since you request a 30-frame selection, but have a precision of 29, the calculation can skip a frame. Consider using 15 or 16 frames instead.

Comment: Hmm thx for the answer but that's not it. Tried it, and there is still a mistake. I've tried this other code : [link]http://www.ben-daglish.net/moon.shtml but same mistake... Weird right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function julday(year, month, day) {
    if (year < 0) { year ++; }
    var jy = parseInt(year);
    var jm = parseInt(month) +1;
    if (month <= 2) {jy--;  jm += 12;   } 
    var jul = Math.floor(365.25 *jy) + Math.floor(30.6001 * jm) + parseInt(day) + 1720995;
    if (day+31*(month+12*year) >= (15+31*(10+12*1582))) {
        var ja = Math.floor(0.01 * jy);
        jul = jul + 2 - ja + Math.floor(0.25 * ja);
    }
    return jul;
}

function moonphase(year,month,day) {
    var n = Math.floor(12.37 * (year -1900 + ((1.0 * month - 0.5)/12.0)));
    var RAD = 3.14159265/180.0;
    var t = n / 1236.85;
    var t2 = t * t;
    var aas = 359.2242 + 29.105356 * n;
    var am = 306.0253 + 385.816918 * n + 0.010730 * t2;
    var xtra = 0.75933 + 1.53058868 * n + ((1.178e-4) - (1.55e-7) * t) * t2;
    xtra += (0.1734 - 3.93e-4 * t) * Math.sin(RAD * aas) - 0.4068 * Math.sin(RAD * am);
    var i = (xtra > 0.0 ? Math.floor(xtra) :  Math.ceil(xtra - 1.0));
    var j1 = julday(year,month,day);
    var jd = (2415020 + 28 * n) + i;
    return (j1-jd + 30)%30;
}
```

not that i fully understand it, but this should work fine. It's a (straight) port of some Basic code by Roger W. Sinnot from Sky & Telescope magazine, March 1985 ... talk about old school.

if you try with 16 sept 2016 it will give 15. same as 21 sept 2002, which was the [actual day](http://lunaf.com/lunar-calendar/2002/) of the fullmoon

Comment: _if you try with 16 sept 2016 it will give 15. same as 21 sept 2002, which was the actual day of the fullmoon_. I don't really understand what you mean. "16" is suppose to be the number for full moon right ? and the 16 september is a full moon right ? So, why it gives the number "15" on the 16 september ?

Comment: I guess it depends on which range do you use... This returns a value in the 0-29 range, so 0 is new moon and 15 is a full moon. If you need a 1-30 range (keyframes i suppose?) just +1 the returned value

Comment: _italic_If you need a 1-30 range (keyframes i suppose?) _italic_ yes. But if I add +1 to the returned value it's not correct for some date (and for some it is). Example : 5 october 2017 is full moon. But without adding +1, the value already 16 (full moon), so when adding +1 it's = 17 and not showing full moon... But 16 september 2016 is now correct... Hard one this question right ? I don't understand why sometimes it works and for some dates it doesn't...